# Merge column with date and time

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the table:

```
CLIENT NUMBER (15,0),
REGION NUMBER (5,0),
DATA DATE,
TIME NVARCHAR2(10)
```

I want to merge columns DATE (dd.mm.yy) and TIME (hh24.mi).

Tried to use this:
`SELECT TO_DATE(DATA || TIME, 'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi') FROM table`

And got this error:     ORA-01843: not a valid month

How to solve it?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST

INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES (12345678, 34567, TO_DATE ('18.08.20', 'dd.mm.yy'), '13:16' );

INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES (12345678, 34567, TO_DATE ('18.08.20','dd.mm.yy'), '14:01' );

INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES (12345678, 45678, TO_DATE ('18.08.20','dd.mm.yy'), '14:16' );

INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES (12345678, 34567, TO_DATE ('19.08.20', 'dd.mm.yy'),'09:01' );

INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES (34567896, 23456, TO_DATE ('19.08.20','dd.mm.yy'), '09:15' );

INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES (12345678, 34567, TO_DATE ('19.08.20', 'dd.mm.yy'),'09:28' );
```

Comment: can you provide the data in the table 2 or 3 rows sample ?

Comment: Did you ever hear about the Y2K-Problem?

Comment: Why?  Your data model is flawed.  In oracle a DATE data type _includes_ time, down to the second.  In oracle, a TIMESTAMP data type _includes_ time, down to the nano-second.  Keeping date and time separate makes no sense.  Keeping either an a char type is a recipe for problems.

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic might be simplest solution:

```
select data + (substr(tm, 1, 2) + substr(tm, -2) / 60) / 24
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use to_timestamp instead of to_date :

```
 SELECT TO_timestamp(data || time, 'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi') from test;
```

Some times if your NLS time format is set differently also you will not be able to see the particular date format you desire, before running above statement i would suggest running this statement.

```
 alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'dd.mm.yy HH24:MI';
```

Comment: Same error... I updated the table data in the question

Comment: which version of oracle are you using ?

Comment: I am running oracle 12c , my answer works perfectly fine for sample data and scripts you provided. Please recheck with your post add more details.

Comment: I tested TO_timestamp(data || time, 'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi') and it works perfectly unless you are using different Oracle version.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should give you a DATE value that encompasses your DATA and TIME (columns):

```
select
  to_date (
    to_char( DATA, 'DD.MM.RR' ) || ' ' || time -- eg 18.08.20 13:16 
  , 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI'
  ) dt
from test ;
```

You could add a virtual column to your table, and use the TO_DATE() call (as above) to generate the DATE values:

```
alter table test
add dt DATE generated always as (
  to_date (
    to_char( DATA, 'DD.MM.RR' ) || ' ' || time
  , 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI'
  )
) virtual ;

-- Table altered.

-- check
select 
  dt  dt_not_formatted
, to_char( dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) dt_formatted
, data old_date
, time old_time
from test ;

-- result
   DT_NOT_FORMATTED           DT_FORMATTED     OLD_DATE    OLD_TIME 
___________________ ______________________ ____________ ___________ 
18-AUG-20           2020-08-18 13:16:00    18-AUG-20    13:16       
18-AUG-20           2020-08-18 14:01:00    18-AUG-20    14:01       
18-AUG-20           2020-08-18 14:16:00    18-AUG-20    14:16       
19-AUG-20           2020-08-19 09:01:00    19-AUG-20    09:01       
19-AUG-20           2020-08-19 09:15:00    19-AUG-20    09:15       
19-AUG-20           2020-08-19 09:28:00    19-AUG-20    09:28
```

Alternatively, you could add a DATE column to the original table, and UPDATE it by using the DATA and TIME values:

```
alter table test add dtnew date ;

update test
set dtnew = to_date(
  to_char( DATA, 'DD.MM.RR' ) || ' ' || time
, 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI'
) ;
```

DBfiddle:

[{1} virtual column](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3abcbede220cae9b926f00edb3f35771)

[{2} DATE column](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=56aaf54ad77342a4fccc6f942ecad263)